How can I fill a tapered gap behind the skirt board?
This is a new build. The contractor was not detail oriented, to say the least. The drywall folks installed all of the walls such that none are square. The stair treads were custom crafted from local timber. As you can see in the photos, the installation was rough to say the least. There is 3/4" difference between the wall and the skirt at the last step in a eight stair run.
The contractor slapped a 1.5" wide piece of lattice, which left a 3/4" overhang over the skirt board at the top of the stairs, and 1/16" of an inch over the skirt board on the last stair. The skirt board on the other side is flush to the wall from top to bottom. Of course the "odd" side is on the longest and tallest wall, so having it plastered into square would take a talented craftsman (one I have yet to find).
How can I fix this gap (or give the illusion that it is fixed) so that the new trim will look clean, neat and even? The house looks like a farmhouse with shaker features. Any suggestions would be appreciated.


UPDATE:  Per the ideas given here, I came up with the idea to "layer" the trim to help divide the difference in distance between the wall, the skirt board and the trim, from the top of the stairs to the bottom.  From the attached diagram, you can see (#1) the tapered gap behind the skirt board, (#2) what the builder did to "hide" the gap (this goes with the first to photos I posted), and (#3) my thoughts...(a) Trim the lattice to be 1" on the top, tapered down to the 1 3/4" at the bottom of the stairs. (b) Cut rounded edge trim (think 3/4" flooring with the tongue facing toward the stairs as in the last photo) to be 1 1/4" at the top of the stairs and 1 1/2" at the bottom of the stairs.  (c) Add a transition block before reinstalling the floor trim.  I hope this will soften the overall look, look more finished, and reduce the overhang of the lattice at the top of the stairs as compared to the bottom of the stairs.


Of course, I will need to paint the whole thing white or a muted color that matches the walls so to make the imperfections disappear.

3/4" isn't much but it's still enough to trip you up - and make you fall down the stairs.  I'd want rid of that stupid strip immediately and then start thinking about how to do a  better job

This is a bummer of a situation. Here are the facts as I see them.

This is a framing issue at its core. Drywallers rarely hold blame for things being wonky, as their role is simply to cover framing. Sure, the finish job can be sloppy, but that won't result in what we see here.

The stairwell should've been built with parallel walls. That's a fundamental requirement of a good job.

Since it wasn't, the skirts should've been installed first and the treads and risers should've been fit to them. That's actually how you'd do it even with parallel walls. Nothing is perfectly straight and flat in wood framing.

The laws of space-time being what they are, there's no easy fix to arrive at a professional outcome.


I think what I'd do is to build out the skirt to a uniform thickness adequate to cover the gap. It's a putzy job, but it's the only way to make the trim parallel to the wall and still cover the gap behind. This leaves you with stairs that themselves aren't uniform in width, but most eyes won't see that.
There are a couple ways this could be done:

Add another 3/4" board, fitted to the stair treads and risers. This calls for some advanced carpentry, but is possible. You'd use scribing techniques to transfer shapes to a board laid over the stairs.

Move the existing board inward. If, by chance, it's not fastened particularly well, you could trace the stairs on it, remove it, and mill out along the trace lines. Then you can reinstall it with 3/4" spacers behind.


In either case you'll need a cap. A flat lattice probably isn't ideal, so consider a combination of moldings to achieve a suitable coordinating style. Something 3/4" or just thicker, to cover the spacers, might be enough.
Then, you'll have to deal with the thickened skirt at the landing. This could be done with a plinth block of at least the thickness of the final skirt plus a small reveal. The oddity of this situation is now reduced to that fairly inconspicuous point.

+1, would do more for "putzy" I learned a new word today! Would routing the overhang of the lattice off with a flush-cut bit and an offset trim router work? Then fill in the hole at the bottom if the baseboard doesn't cover it?

@Triplefault, I think I will remove the lattice from both sides of the stairwell, try to stack more substantial piece of trim and then add a cap so clean-up the armature look and, again, trick the eye with a bit of bulk.  I'll likely use a block at the joints between the skirt and the trim so that I can use the same width trim as in the rest of the house.  Thank you so much for your comments!

@Triplefault, that's the crux of this question--how to avoid a wedge. What you suggest would result in exactly that.

A perfect solution for this would indeed be labor intensive, but I think a decent solution can be achieved.
Simply trim the current "lattice board" so that it is flush with the skirting board (meaning cutting the overhanging part). It would cover the gap between the skirting board and the wall, and I suspect that most people won't notice (or care) that the "skirting board" width gradually widens from top to bottom. I would do this cut by scribing the bottom of the "lattice board" against the skirting board (with a knife or even a pencil), remove the "lattice board" and then cut it on a bandsaw just shy of the line. Final sanding to fit after it's installed back on top of the skirting board. Use wood filler to even out any issues and paint it.
At the bottom, I would suggest putting a plinth block to cover the difference in apparent thickness between the skirting board and "lattice board" and the baseboard.

Thank you for your thoughts!  Part I: I'm playing with something similar to your suggestions.  First, to trim that piece of lattice (keep the other side the same as there is no gap on that side) so that there is a smaller tapered overhang (maybe reducing the top to 1/4" instead of 3/4") at the top of the stairs, and making the bottom flush to the skirt board (taking off 1/8").

Part II: We have a bunch of extra maple floor boards.  If I trim the floor boards to over the lattice strip, putting the tongue side out I can further correct the 3/4" difference by putting it about 1/4" over the lattice strip on the top and flush to the strip on the bottom, so now the difference from top to bottom is 1/4" - hopefully barely noticeable (and offering a softer line).  I still will use the plinth blocks for further distraction.  Thoughts?

@Firefly I'm not following your explanation. Perhaps update the original question with this update and propsal?

I just updated my original question :)
